# Calling c# dll (which parses XML file) from my c++ application to return array / list to c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, interop

I have a simple c++ Application. This Application is just printing text out. 
I have also a  c# .dll NET 3.5 which parses complex xml files, extracts values and saves them into a List. Its like 2 Classes with 4 methods. They open a file, parse the xml and store it into a List. When the c# .dll is done, it has a List with 10000 values;

Since i do not want to write the complex parsing XML in c++, i would like to use my c# xml parsing .dll.

Is it possible for me, to call my c# .dll from inside my c++ application, let the c# .dll parse a specified xml file, and return that created List, with the parsed xml values, to my c++ application?

In my c++ application i would proceed to modify the data within the returned list.

edit: **i would be using vc++ (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010)**

edit2: the vc++ app would be an expension/plug-in to another bigger Application. I would register the plug-in to that bigger application, and every time i press the icon in the menu, my vc++ application would be started

edit3: Has anyone experience with such a task? I kinda need a clear yes or no if it is possible.

edit4: **i do want to avoid reading  files that have been written by my .net .dll. I want my c++ app to send a string to my .net .dll and receive back a list/array object. Or is this a bad idea and i should do the xml parsing in c++ itself?**

Comment: I think you need to use C++.net instead cause It will need .net Dlls.and using that DLL through C++ needs your headers. you cn also make it a Com and use some underlying Windows Specific libraries to access that COM

Comment: There always is the Microsoft XML parser. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb190600.aspx Also, through googling, you will find loads of other C++ XML parsers. Passing data around is no problem, as long as you get the signature right, you also have to pin the pointers.. plus.. I think.. it was easiest to create the objects in managed code. So again, you would have C++ App -> combined C++ dll -> C# dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but its kinda hard. One way to do it is to use C++ to load up CLR and execute your function, something like this:

*code inspired by Blizzhackers.cc*

```
void StartNET()
{
   DWORD result;
   ICLRRuntimeHost* pCLR = NULL;

   CorBindToRuntimeEx(NULL, L"wks", NULL, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID*)&pCLR);
   pCLR->Start();

   pCLR->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"C:\\myNET.dll", L"myNet.Program", L"Main", L"arg", &result);

   pCLR->Stop();
}
```

This C++ code will execute the `int Main(string arg)` function from `namespace myNet` and `class Program`, by that I mean:

myNET.dll:

```
namespace myNet
{
     class Program
     {
            int Main(string arg)
            {
                    //and here you can run your XML parser:

                    List<string> myList = XMLParse();

                    FileStream fs = new Filestream("xmllist.txt");
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

                    foreach(string s in myList)
                         sw.WriteLine(s);

                    sw.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                    return 1;
            }

            List<string> XMLParse()
            {
                    //Your code here
                    return aList;
            }
     }

}
```

And after this you could use c++ to get the files from xmllist.txt, something like:

```
vector<char[]> getList()
{
      vector<char[]> *myVector = new vector<char>;
      ifstream cin("xmllist.txt");
      while(!cin.eof())
      {
          char line[100];
          cin >> line;
          myVector.push(line);
      }
      cin.close();
      return myVector;
}
```

I don't know if this last function works, but you get the general idea.

Comment: thx for the infos!!! but i do want to avoid reading  files that have been written by my .net .dll. I want my c++ app to receive a List Object from my .net .dll. c++ sends a string to .net .dll and receives a list.

Comment: @Gero Then I suggest you look into http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 . I tried it once and it worked. Note: you will be using COM.

Answer (score 1):

I created a managed/unmanaged dll in C++ some time ago. (Note though that C++.net has not the easiest syntax.)

Actually, I do not know where to start now, maybe this has the information http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/101918-Mixing-Managed-and-Unmanaged-C-in-a-DLL . It certainly was well possible with.. VS 2005? With that, you can have both managed an unmanaged code in one binary/assembly, and thus call the C# dll.

Apart from that, you can wrap your C# objects as COM objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285.aspx . Then you can use COM interop.

In each case, marshalling the input/output would require some trial and error - it is not that obvious if you have never done it before.

Actually, this link should cover it all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx .

Comment: i have experience with c#, but no with c++. The whole area with vc++ +c# is kinda new to me. There is no problem to learn c++ what is required; i kinda just need  the infos if its possible, it makes sense and path how to do it.